# How to substract (last column, last row) minus (last column, first row) from a df in python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a dataframe with index being datetime and the columns with intigers. I am trying to do the following (last column last row minus last column first row). I am having difficulty getting the correct output. Please help.

```
df8['new_port'] = df8.mean(axis=1)
print(df8)

print(df8['new_port'].iloc[-1:])
print(df8['new_port'].iloc[:1])
print(df8['new_port'].iloc[:1] - df8['new_port'].iloc[-1:])
```

Output is the following
[image]

Comment: `print(df8['new_port'].iat[1] - df8['new_port'].iat[-1])`

Comment: first select the last column and take the different between the last and first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're choosing a set of elements when you do `df8['new_port'].iloc[-1:]`.

You have to remove the colon to just choose the last element.

```
df8['new_port'].iloc[-1] # last row element from your last column 
df8['new_port'].iloc[0] # first row element from your last column
```

```
df8.iloc[-1,-1] # last row last column
df8.iloc[0,-1] # first row last column
```

```
df8.iat[-1,-1]  # last row last column
df8.iat[0,-1] # first row last column
```

Or much easier as Sayandip Dutta said it

```
df8['new_port'].iat[1] - df8['new_port'].iat[-1]
```